# Import extension file automatically in flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I'm using AndroidStudio to develop flutter, I have a file named `extensions.dart` for my extensions, when I want to use an extension inside another file, I have to import extensions file manually (like `import '../../../../utils/extensions.dart';`) otherwise auto compilation doesn't work and also this process is kind of annoying. How can I force AndroidStudio to import extensions file automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Write all the imports possible in one dart file. Then you just need to import that one file containing all the imports.

Comment: I'm doing this already, I'm talking about importing automatically, not issue with multiple files!